# Avoid threshold limit with view using "Or condition" on person columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, filter, list-view-threshold, indexed-column

Here is my issue: I have a sharepoint 2013 list with more than 5 000 items inside.
In order to avoid threshold limit I indexed several columns and created views using these columns.
Most of the views works fine, but some views are filtering on several person columns using the "OR" condition, for these views I still get the threhsold limit error. 
Here is an example of view having this issue :

"In charge 1" equals [Me]
OR
"In charge 2" equals [Me]

At first "In charge" was only one column, but as it is not possible to index multi value columns I splitted this column in two columns.
The same view with "AND" instead of "OR" is working fine...So I understood this issue is coming from the "OR" Condition, and it seems we can't use this condition on lists exceeding 5 000 items...

Do you know any workaround for this need (filter using "or" condition on large list)? I was thinking about using filter webpart, but without success for now.

I also tried adding a first condition using an other indexed column in order to have less than 5 000 items resul, but it's still not working.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Or condition with indexed columns in large list seems to work fine on SharePoint Online...anyone know what it the behavior on 2016?